# Arabic font comparison

Tags: android, comparison, arabic

I have a database in Arabic, and I need to retrieve some rows from database based of a query that takes a term as input as the following code.

```
String sqlSTRing = "SELECT term, termNT, definition FROM " + TABLE_Definitions + " WHERE termNT = ?";
Cursor mCursor2 = db.rawQuery(sqlSTRing, new String[] {"سلام"});
```

The problem is with the Arabic font, when the SQL string is comparing the given word with the same in the database its not finding it. 
I also noticed that any comparison inside Android for Arabic fonts give false. For example, using the selection tool I was getting a word from the webview. I take the first letter, and compare it with the alphabet to know with what the word starts.

```
fistLetter.equals("ا");
```

even when `firstLetter` is `"ا"`, the comparison returns `false`.

I tried using the `ArabicReshaper` class, but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm really not sure that your problem has anything to do with fonts or shaping. You are supposed to be at the level of Unicode characters and not font display. Did you try the same with simple Latin letters?

Comment: hy amir thank u for your reply, in fact I have tried the following: ("ا").equals("ا"); it gave true, but when I retrieve the words  or the letters from another source, the same letter would give a false result. In fact, I made a turnover, I used compareTo. if(firstLetter.compareTo("ا") == 63590)) then do smg. luckily its working. any other suggestion would be truly appreciated

Comment: By the way I didn't have this problem in string comparison with ios developing, I don't know why its occurring it with android, though I'm using the same sources.

Comment: I have reverted to @kiamlaluno's edit, which is clearly a better version.

Comment: This is an old question, luckily the string comparison has been fixed in the newer versions of Android.